# Gas Leakage Circuit

Tags: led, transistors, sensor, circuit-analysis, gas

What Transistor should i use instead of SL100?

thanks[image]

Comment: This 2N2222 would be the closest you could probably get http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1662272.pdf

Comment: This is not a question about a "Gas Leakage Circuit" this is a basic transistor selection/substitution question.

Comment: You could place LED1 in series with R4 to help carbon footprint.Also use a 7805 to replace R1 and Z1 .

Answer (score 4):

Any general-purpose NPN transistor will work in that application. 2N4401, 2N3904, 2N2222, etc.

Comment: Just about to say that! You beat me.

Comment: What is the best program to simulate this circuit with?

Comment: The CircuitLab simulator built into this website will simulate it.